# How should I properly refresh a partial that renders a partial (refreshing via js results in page in a page)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Update 2 - marzapower's came through again.. the success section in the ajax was causing the problem - the  explanation below..

UPDATE:

marzapower's answer works well (see it below) but I needed this on a timer.

Works on the first time, but on reload it displays html markup instead of just the content.. I tried html_safe int refreshnews.js.erb file but it still doesn't work.

If I use single quotes before <% %> it bombs because 'news/newsfeed' has them too - kept single quotes and changes the partial name to double quotes.. still doesn't work right..

refreshnews.js.erb:

```
$("#refreshscribbles").html("<%= j(render(:partial=> 'news/newsfeed', :locals=>{:news=>@news}).html_safe) %>");
```

I've tried all kinds of changes - single quotes, .html_safe on the outer right parenthesis, etc..  but this is what i get instead of clean content.

RETURNED CONTENT:

[image: sample output]

```
news.js
$(document).ready(function() 
{

  setInterval(

     function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/refreshnews.js',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function(result) 
            {
              $('#refreshscribbles').html(result)
            }
        });
    }
  , 500);
});
```

Otherwise, the solution is perfect - any ideas why html_safe isn't working? Should I do something in the format.js ?

---

I have a news feed that I'm working on (think facebook news feed).  I need to update the feed without reloading the entire page again. (The entire feed loads at once - it is not a bunch of small loads.. Rather one big load.. like returning data from a sql select)

I'm dynamically rendering a partial which renders another partial based upon values in the data..

I stole a javascript solution, and worked it into my form, but the minute it reloads the div section it uses the application layout. I've tried layout=>false etc to no avail.  I've tried in the format.js respond_to section, setting layout for the controller (with except also), just about everything published out there to no avail.

What I'd really like to do is simply refresh the div with a partial without having the app layout being included.  (Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.92)

news controller:

index.html.erb

```
<div class="actions" id="refreshscribbles">
  <%=render :partial=> 'news/newsfeed', :locals=>{:news=>@news}%>
</div>
```

_newsfeed.html.erb:

```
<% news.each do |act| %>
  <%=render :partial=> act["object_type"], :locals=>{:activity=>act}%>
  <br><%= act["object_type"]%>
  <hr>
<%end %>
```

news.js (note, I've tried refreshnews in the url, etc, but it all just pulls back a page within a page at best).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timelyrefreshScribbleFeeds = function(){
    url = '/news'
    $.get(url,function(data,status){
      $('#refreshscribbles').html(data)
      return false
    });
  };
  setInterval(timelyrefreshScribbleFeeds,600);
});
```

news controller:

```
def refreshnews
  @news=News.get_newsstream(viewer_id,  @per_page, @current_page)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html   #tried :layout => false, etc, to no avail
    format.json { render  json: @news }
  end
end
```

refreshnews.html.erb  (empty - used to simply ignore no method error)

routes.rb

```
get  "refreshnews"  => "news#refreshnews", :as => "refreshnews"
```

How would I refresh this div via ajax/jquery? I've seen multiple solutions but not one for rendering partials that render partials etc.  What is wrong with the code / solution above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call the refreshnews using the JS format:

```
def refreshnews
  @news=News.get_newsstream(viewer_id,  @per_page, @current_page)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

using `url = '/refreshnews.js'` in the javascript `$.get` calls:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/refreshnews.js',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

You'll need a corresponding template file:

#### refreshnews.js.erb

```
$("#refreshscribbles").html("<%= j(render :partial=> 'news/newsfeed', :locals=>{:news=>@news}) %>");
```

Once all this is done, you should see that the app calls the `refreshnews` action and gets a js script that will update the main `div` with all the updated data you need.

Comment: I added this and used a timer to reload the partial - it works initially, but then subsequent requests show html text. I tried html_safe to no avail. I've played with single quotes, double quotes, etc and it either stops working or displays the markup text along with the normal text.  Any ideas?

Here is the refreshnews.js.erb code:
$("#refreshscribbles").html("<%= j(render(:partial=> 'news/newsfeed', :locals=>{:news=>@news}).html_safe) %>");

Comment: Get rid of the `success:` param in `$.ajax`. Since it's expecting a script, it will automatically execute the remote javascript, thus updating the page. I created a test application to test this and works really good.